# Process more than one files at the same time in a synch way via azure functions

Tags: c#, azure, http, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function which extracts the name and file URLs from a blob container and then send this information to another function to process these files (unpack them and save them in Datalake)

For extartction of blobs:

```
string storageConnectionString = @"myconnstring";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("Container");

IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = new IListBlobItem[0];

foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
     {                
        if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory)
           {
              CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)blobItem;
              blobs = directory.ListBlobs(true);                    
           }

      }

 await ProcessBlobs(blobs);
```

and the function for process the bolbs:

```
public static async Task ProcessBlobs(IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs)
    {

        var tasks = blobs.Select(currentblob =>
        {
            string FileUrl = currentblob.Uri.ToString();
            string FileName = currentblob.Uri.Segments.Last();
            //string content = "{ \"fileUri\": \""+ currentblob.Uri.ToString()+ "\" , \"fileName\": \""+ currentblob.Uri.Segments.Last()+"\"}";

            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "fileUri", currentblob.Uri.ToString() },
                    { "fileName", currentblob.Uri.Segments.Last() }
                };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            string baseURL = @"https://<afu>.azurewebsites.net/api/process_zip_files_by_http_trigger?code=45"; ;
            //string urlToInvoke = string.Format("{0}&name={1}", baseURL, FileUrl, FileName);


            return RunAsync(baseURL, content);
        });
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    public static async Task RunAsync(string i_URL, FormUrlEncodedContent content)
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync(i_URL, content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        log.info(responseString);
    }
```

the function `RunAsync`process files asynchronous.

My question is now:
Is it generally possible to process blobs parallel, but in a synchronized way? Do you have any better and simpler idea, to implement my aim?

Comment: Why would you do this synchronously ? Just curiosity and it could help people giving more accurate answer.

Comment: To be sure every file is processed

Comment: Running your process synchronously won't ensure your file are all processed. This appliy also with asynchronous. you should handle exception and retry if needed to be sure your file are processed and add some logging.

Comment: Am I in a right way for calling an azure function from another azure function asynchronously?

Comment: Probably there are always multiple ways, but you need to explain in details what youre trying to achieve to get one of the right way

Comment: Kaja, I have some issues to save files in a DataLake. I received Unknow Host error. Have you any extract of code about this? What is the adlsAccountFQDN? I not found this in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the best use cases for [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview). Specifically, the [Fan-Out/Fan-In Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview#fan-in-out).

You would need 4 functions in total

1. **GetBlobList [Activity Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#activity-functions)**
   This is where you get the list of blobs to process. You would just get the list of blobs instead of the actual blobs instead.
2. **ProcessBlob [Activity Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#activity-functions)**
   This function takes a blob path, fetches the blob and processes it.
3. **[Orchestrator Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#orchestrator-functions)**
   This is the function that calls the GetBlobList function, loops over the list of blob paths returned and calls the ProcessBlob function for each blob path.
4. **Starter Function ([Client Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#client-functions))**
   This function simply triggers a run of the orchestration. This is usually a HTTP triggered function.

If you are new to Durable Functions, its best to walk through the [quickstart doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp) to understand the different types of functions required.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint :) I have a new problem, may be you can help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752442/self-referencing-loop-while-there-are-two-activity-functions-in-my-durable-azure